# Tile on In Concrete Slab hydronic heating

Tags: flooring, tile

Context: Bought a 25 year old house that had italian tile what appeared to be thinset directly to the concrete slab. Slab has in slab hydronic heating. We pulled the tile up earlier last year and put wood down. Then had a pipe burst and ruined ALL the flooring. So up came the wood flooring. Not going to do that again. Going to put Porcelain tile down now. There is some debate about how to set the tile in 2024. (original tile floor looked pretty good, no cracks, very few hollow spots). We are going with 8" x48" porcelain tile and the slab is pretty level with very cracks, in good shape. Contractor got most of the glue/bonding agent they used for the wood. But still some material left on the slab. Question: Do we get fancy with something like a Schluter Ditra mat system to ensure adherence, reduce cracking of tile and transmit heat? Or can we go with more of an anti fracture membrane adhesive with thinset straight to tile? pro's and cons of both? (I'm being given a choice but haven't seen pricing yet. I would assume the Schulter will be much more expensive.)